# How can I set the title programmatically

Tags: android

How can I set the current view title(by title I mean the text shown below battery & time(in the image below that would be "Menu Sample") programmatically? I found many examples using manifest file but none from code.

[image: Android Set Title Programatically]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Activity.setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) - `setTitle("My New Awesome Title!");`

Answer (score 8):

Like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setTitle("This is my Title");


    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.foo_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

or

```
youractivity.setTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
actionBar.setTitle("Hello");
```

** targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or greater.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" ... />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to change actionBar's text pragmatically in onCreate() method

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("yourString");
```